# Adding delete symbol to each row in the table

Tags: angular

I want to implement  the `Edit` button where it will show the `Action` column with the delete icon in every row in the table. How do I add a "Delete" symbol in the Action column to every column in the table once the user clicks on the `Edit button`? I've added an example in the table.

I am new to Angular. I have added some of my code.

```
<div class="button">
  <button mat-button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </button>
</div>


<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="subjectData">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject_Code">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Code }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Name }}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  export class SubjectListComponent implements OnInit{

        displayedColumns: string[] = ['Number', 'Subject_Code',                            
                                      'Subject_Name'];
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to add an action column which will have 2 buttons - edit and delete per row ?

Comment: the action column will have just the delete button. The Add button will appear another '<div>' column on top of the table.  I will do the  `<div>` section by my own. Btw, can the Edit button trigger the both `<div>` section and the action column together?

Comment: I have built a library called Easy Angular https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez that makes building this sort of thing quite easy. Here is a demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5

Comment: Yes the delete  button will appear in every column with the details  from the database.

Comment: @AdrianBrand but i want  the edit button to show the both Action Column and the `<div>` section

Answer (score 0):

You could simple add a variable to track whether the edit button is clicked or not.

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="subjectData">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject_Code">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Code }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.Subject_Name }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Subject Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div class="button">
          <button mat-button><i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="element.edit = true"></i> Edit </button>
          <button mat-button><i class="fa fa-delete" *ngIf="element.edit"></i> Delete </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note: please delete this `edit` property for all the rows if you are sending the data to any API.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to iterate over subjectData

see this code snippet

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Cnic</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="click" *ngFor="let student of students">
                <td>{{student.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{student.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                <td>{{student.cnic}}</td>
                <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="[student._id]"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp; Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onRemoveClick(student._id)"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp; Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: is this is what you are looking for]

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you want to be able to display a list of data from the database? Correct me if I'm wrong. If this, in fact, is the case, Mr. Ali is right. You would need to use an `*ngFor` loop that iterates through an array that is defined in your component's ts file. We actually just did a project using this in class when building an online banking application. I will show you a sample of my code here:

```
`<div class="card-body">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Nickname</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Rewards</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor = "let account of accounts">
   <td ><button [routerLink] = "['/accounts', account.account_id]"> Click to View </button><br> </td>

  <td>{{ account.nickname}}</td>

    <td style="font-size: 12px">{{ account.balance }}</td>


    <td> {{ account.type }}</td>    <td> {{account.rewards }}</td>    <td><button [routerLink] = "[account.account_id, '/update-account']">Edit</button></td>    </tr>    </table>
`
```

You can see here that we have accomplished what you are trying to do with your delete button twice.

We first define table headers, which will serve as our column names. Two of those column names are 'View' and 'Edit'. Then, we used the `*ngFor` to iterate over each account belonging to the customer with `"let account of accounts"`. If you are familiar with Java, specifically `foreach` loops, you should understand what this is doing.

Finally, using the `<td>` tags, we enter in the information--if any-- that needs to be displayed in the same order as we indicated our column names. In the `<td>` for View, we display a button object that navigates to the appropriate route, and we see this happen again with the `<td>` for 'Edit'.

I hope this helps you. I hated Angular when I first started, and now I'm guiding my class through every project!

Comment: I just looked at it again, and you would need to create another container and create a new `<th>` and `<td>` combination for delete. the column name would be 'Delete', and between the data tags, you would create a button object that would run your delete method with `(click)`.

Comment: Please update the answer with the respective code, then.

Comment: still not working. Probably because i have added  `displayedColumns: string[] = ['Number', 'Subject_Code',                            
                                      'Subject_Name']; `  in typescript.